# Similar javascript code for this?

Tags: javascript

I'm not very good at javascript and I wanted to know if doing this is possible in javascript?

```
<?php

        $str = file_get_contents('splashes.txt');

        $splashes = explode("\n",$str);

        $ind = rand(1, count($splashes)) -1;


        echo $splashes[$ind];

?>
```

What would the equivalent of that be in javascript?

Comment: Since Javascript is client-side, there isn't an exact equivalent of `file_get_contents()`. You'd have to use something like AJAX for that. Otherwise, there are equivalents for `explode()` (`String.split(delimiter)`) and `rand()` (I don't know what the equivalent is).

Comment: A literal solution: http://phpjs.org/

Answer (score 3):

Swap `file_get_contents()` with an XHR request, which may be blocked by Same Origin Policy.

Swap `explode()` with `split()`.

Swap `rand()` with `Math.random()` and `count()` with the `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to do exactly the same on a web page with JavaScript, since it is a waste of bandwidth to load 'splashes.txt' if it is a huge file.

Yes, you want to show a random splash on the page. However, if 'splashes.txt' is a small file, it is much more better to convert it to a JavaScript array, e.g.

```
var splashes = [
    'splash 1',
    'splash 2',
    ...
];
var splashIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * splashes.length);
alert(splashes[splashIdx]);
```

If 'splashes.txt' is a huge file, just read it with PHP (exactly the same as the code in your question), and load it with XHR (requires jQuery). e.g.

```
$.get('/get_splash.php', function(data) {
    alert(data);
)
```